# Cheated audit with faked tags?

Tags: support, review, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I've failed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/4019543) audit on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21475490/waitformultipleobjects-alternative-with-stdthread) question.

The problem is I've seen in my audit window something else as there actually is. The question in audit had [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tag, while actually it has no such tag, and I should have never seen that question because of the tag filter in close queue.

I've chosen to close as **unclear what you are asking** because I couldn't see what that has to do with JavaScript.

Please don't add random tags to audit questions and expect us to take no action.

Comment: The audit in question: http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/4019543

Comment: I always click the link to the actual post before I take any action if I am uncertain about the review task. This is how I spot the randomly added tag and determine that it is an audit.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett the audit doesn't show [javascript] tag, and I'm sure I've seen that tag. Otherwise I wouldn't be able to see that question because of filter on [javascript], [java] and [jquery].

Comment: From looking at the audit via the above link, it looks like another issue is that it doesn't show the same tags that you saw at the time.

Comment: @ŁukaszL.: Just commented about that.

Comment: I guess the issue is that there won't be enough suitable audits if you filter to [some-super-obscure-tag]

Comment: The random tags are added so when you are filtering by tag in the queue, you actually get audits (this used to not happen).  But rather than finding an audit in your tag, it just adds the tag whether the question had it or not.  Obviously works great for "known bad" audits, but can be confusing at best for "known good" audits"

Comment: But the idea of tag filter is to filter the questions from my field of expertise. How am I supported to do good reviews if that assumption is broken? Anyway, adding anything gibberish to the question makes usually question bad and should be used only for bad-audits.

Comment: ^You would skip. I don't disagree with you but I think its a very minor issue. If a question is good then a wrong tag isn't reason for closure.

Comment: @OGHaza but wrong tags are a reason for reaction, so 'leave open' should also fail the audit? Am I expected to 'edit' the question? Will audit check if I remove gibberish tag? Otherwise, the audit is simply wrong. If it's by design, I will abstain from auditing.

Comment: But if you'd hit "edit" you'd have been told ["You passed. Editing to fix minor problems is always good; Leave Open is also appropriate for questions like this."](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/4020358). If you see a good question with a wrong tag in the CV queue I absolutely think the only appropriate actions are Edit or Leave Open (+ go leave a comment or whatever if you feel the desire).

Comment: It'd be slightly different if it added a tag that did make the question completely unclear, a question for which the answer greatly varied by database tagged [mysql][sql-server] where the audit system added the [sql-server], but that'd be an edge case and you'd be much more likely to get thrown an obviously closable question as "good question" (as indicated by number of threads on meta about that happening)

Comment: In my opinion, abstain from reviewing is the correct response, and if there was enough noise on meta about it then maybe a feedback mechanism would be created to allow us to review audits.

Answer (score 6):

Are you not getting a bit trigger happy closing that as "Unclear what you're asking"?

**The question is perfectly clear**. It's irrelevant whether the system added [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) to fake an audit, or whether the user accidentally added [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) when posting the question.

An accidental tag being present is the same as there being a typo in the question, and you should have been trying to **edit** this out*, not voting to close because of it.

<sup>*Or skipping... there's never any harm in skipping</sup>

Comment: Of course, there is the risk that a user who sees a question about feature X in language Y mistagged as being language Z will simply say to himself "What is this nonsense? I know that there is no such thing as X in Z. This question is profoundly confused and nothing can be done but to close it." That doesn't seem totally unreasonable.