# Show old audit reviews as they appeared when reviewed

Tags: bug, review-audits

This comes from this question: [Cheated audit with faked tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220242/cheated-audit-with-faked-tags) where the OP says the review audit system added [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) due to him having tag filters applied.

You can see the audit here: https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/4019543

When viewing the audit it looks like we see the original tags of the question, not the tags that the reviewer saw at the time.

This should be corrected.